# Multiple Origin from same s3 bucket in a single cloudfront distribution

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, static-site

I'm using a single s3 bucket for hosting a several static sites, each within a directory. For example: the s3 bucket structure looks like this:

```
├── site1
│   ├── images
│      ├── site-image.jpg
│   ├── index.html
├── site2
│   ├── images
│      ├── site-image.jpg
│   ├── index.html
```

I can access both of these sites using corresponding URLs like this:

- http://example.com/site1/
- http://example.com/site2/

Now I want to add another static site that should be accessible from the root, for example: http://example.com/

I want to add that root site in a separate directory similar to `site1` and `site2`. For example:

```
├── site1
│   ├── images
│      ├── site-image.jpg
│   ├── index.html
├── site2
│   ├── images
│      ├── site-image.jpg
│   ├── index.html
├── root
│   ├── images
│      ├── site-image.jpg
│   ├── index.html
```

I'm having trouble configuring the cloudfront distribution to serve from the `root` directory. I've added separate Origin for each of the directories and created behaviour for both `site1` and `site2` to serve from the corresponding origin while the default behaviour to serve from the origin corresponding to `root`.

This setup seems to be working for the root site only. I can't seem to access `site1` and `site2`.

Is there any other configuration I missed or is this not doable?

Answer (score 0):

S3 folder behavior is different from what you would expect to see from a normal server. The folders in S3 are not actually folders, but are keys (prefixes) instead. Not sure why you are trying to serve 3 sites from one bucket, why not just use 3 buckets and 3 CF distro's? Pricing is not going to be any different.